# I need a query in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table named `Table1` that contains 4 columns.

For ex:

```
id   Field1   Field2   fIELD3
1    A        1        R1
2    A        1        R2
3    B        3        R21
4    A        1        R3
5    B        3        R44
```

I need a query that gives me this result

```
Field1   Field2 
A        1 
B        3
```

Comment: Is field2 dependent upon field1?

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Distinct Field1, Field2 
from Table1
```

Comment: ok man, if i have field3 and field4 ... but i just want to distinct field1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field1,Field2 FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

```
SELECT Field1, Field2 
from Table1 
Group BY Field1, Field2
```

**Method 2:**

```
Select Distinct Field1, Field2 
From Table1
```

**Method 3:**

```
Select Field1, Field2 
From 
    (
      Select Field1, Field2,Row_NUmber() Over(Partition by  Field1, Field2 Order By Field1) AS RN
    ) AS T
 Where RN = 1
```